# Jetty Server based RestServiceJerseyExecutorProvider stuck while reading payload from an HTTPS request

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, jetty, jetty-8

I am having a REST Service based on Jetty HTTPS Connector.

When I am hitting this service using SOAP UI for 200 Total Runs with Just 1 thread, a couple of request get timed out intermittently as *java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out* on SOAP UI Client. [SOAPUI_Conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbLwF.png)

At the Server, while reading the payload from the request object using

```
// Prints Log 1
String payload = org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter.readFromAsString(InputStream in, MediaType type)
// Prints Log 2
```

I saw that the time gap between Log1 and Log 2 are consistently 1 min when the request gets timed out at the client side.

So I tried taking the thread dump at exact time and I found one of the thread as below stack-trace ==>

```
"bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-17" #222 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000019deb800 nid=0x1468 in Object.wait() [0x000000002f1be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.blockReadable(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:449)
    - locked <0x00000000f6a58878> (a org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection$SslEndPoint.blockReadable(SslConnection.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.blockForContent(HttpParser.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:61)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x00000000ee57dfd0> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter.readFromAsString(ReaderWriter.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter.readFromAsString(ReaderWriter.java:160)
    at com.myCorp.myPrd.myPackage.BaseInflector.apply(BaseInflector.java:488)
    at com.myCorp.myPrd.myPackage.BaseInflector.apply(BaseInflector.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.access$100(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker$2.call(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker$2.call(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:333)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder$2$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:865)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:860)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000c31e31f0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

**Jetty details** ==> "Server: Jetty(8.1.16.v20140903)"

**And a wierd thing is that this intermittent request getting timed out is NOT SEEN FOR NON SSL SCENARIO.**

**EDITED** ==> Added server side log for the exact request that timed out at client side.

```
2020-12-04 16:17:14.803 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] c.t.b.b.r.r.jersey.BaseInflector - MyCorp-MyPrd-MyComponent-REST-200004: Request Received for Operation [post]
2020-12-04 16:17:14.803 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-125] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=16421/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=16421/16421 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-125] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap OK NOT_HANDSHAKING consumed=16421 produced=16384
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-125] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/16384 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 16384/16384
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-125] o.e.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - suspended AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-125] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] handle SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} progress=false
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=16421/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=16421/16421 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap OK NOT_HANDSHAKING consumed=16421 produced=16384
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 16384/16384
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.804 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.805 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.805 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.805 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-123] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=14789/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=14789/14789 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.805 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-123] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap OK NOT_HANDSHAKING consumed=14789 produced=14753
2020-12-04 16:17:14.805 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-123] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:17:14.805 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-123] o.e.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - suspended AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82
2020-12-04 16:17:14.805 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-123] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] handle SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} progress=false
2020-12-04 16:17:14.805 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:18:14.807 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=37/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=37/37 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:18:14.809 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap CLOSED NEED_WRAP consumed=37 produced=0
2020-12-04 16:18:14.810 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - unwrap CLOSE SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} Status = CLOSED HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 37 bytesProduced = 0
2020-12-04 16:18:14.810 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] o.e.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - ishut SCEP@7d12c122{l(/127.0.0.1:21918)<->r(/127.0.0.1:8085),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82}}
2020-12-04 16:18:14.811 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NEED_WRAP filled=-1/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:18:14.811 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] wrap CLOSED NOT_HANDSHAKING consumed=0 produced=37
2020-12-04 16:18:14.811 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - wrap CLOSE SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/37/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} Status = CLOSED HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 37
2020-12-04 16:18:14.812 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=-1/0 flushed=37/0
2020-12-04 16:18:14.813 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] o.e.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - oshut SCEP@7d12c122{l(/127.0.0.1:21918)<->r(/127.0.0.1:8085),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82}}
2020-12-04 16:18:14.813 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] o.e.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - close SCEP@7d12c122{l(/127.0.0.1:21918)<->r(/127.0.0.1:8085),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82}}
2020-12-04 16:18:14.813 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=-1/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:18:14.814 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-119 Selector0] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - destroyEndPoint SCEP@7d12c122{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8085),s=1,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82}}
2020-12-04 16:18:14.814 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-119 Selector0] o.e.j.server.AbstractHttpConnection - closed AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82
2020-12-04 16:18:14.814 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-129] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/14753 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=-1/0 flushed=0/0
2020-12-04 16:18:14.814 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 14753/14753
2020-12-04 16:18:14.814 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-129] o.e.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - suspended AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=2,l=34,c=47522},r=82
2020-12-04 16:18:14.814 DEBUG [bwResourceHTTPConnector.qtp-129] org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] handle SslConnection@513197d9 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@11e9d4e5,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=34,c=47522},r=82} progress=false
2020-12-04 16:18:14.815 DEBUG [bw-flowlimit-executor-provider-56] c.t.b.b.r.r.jersey.BaseInflector - MyCorp-MyPrd-MyComponent-REST-200008: Payload for Request
```

Comment: Jetty 8.1.x is EOL (End of Life) - consider upgrading - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/#what-jetty-version

Comment: Hey @JoakimErdfelt, IK Jetty 8.1.X is EOL, But just want to confirm if it's really an issue at Jetty side or anything else.

I have gone through a lot of links and got to know that a lot of SSL related issues in IO layer were fixed in 9.X version. So might be this is one of them. Please can you give me any links to one such. 

If its Jetty issue, then upgrade is the only way out.

Comment: When it comes to SSL/TLS support on Java you must stay up to date, both on the JVM (pay attention to expiration dates on the JVM releases), and Jetty to stay up to date on the evolution of the SSL/TLS specs in the greater community (which happens surprisingly frequently).

Comment: Very true @JoakimErdfelt agreed. Can this be concluded this being a Jetty 8 issue?
 Also a side note that we have a later version of our product with Jetty 9.X where its not reproducible. But am not sure if Jetty can be the only culprit as there's a lot other upgradation in our later product as well.
Your verdict counts a lot as you being a core contributor to Jetty :)

Comment: With the limited information you have provided, this is unlikely to be a Jetty issue, as it points to either your JVM, your OS, or your 3rd party libraries as the culprit.

Comment: Okay @JoakimErdfelt, let me clear out "JVM, your OS, or your 3rd party libraries" meaning it's nothing to do with "org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint"? because I see that this Jetty class itself is dependant over the IO from socket.

Comment: There is not enough information provided to render any more detailed of an answer.  Especially on such an old version of Jetty. (you know that Jetty 11 is out, right?)

Comment: Yep. Hey @JoakimErdfelt please can you check once the connector and executor provider logs if it can help. Also, the box is Windows with JDK8.

Comment: There is no support or analysis of Jetty 8 anymore, it is far too old, and (i just looked this up) literally 15,300+ commits comprising over 4 million lines of change ago.  The classes in your logs don't even exist anymore in mainline Jetty.  Keep in mind that Jetty versioning is (and has been this way since 1995) `<servlet_support>.<major_ver>.<minor_ver>`, which means your usage of 8.1.16 is ... 7 major releases behind where the developers are right now on 11.0.0.

Comment: If you want to migrate to a supported version of Jetty (9.4 or newer), I can help.  But I cannot help with anything around Jetty 9.3 or older (they are all EOL now).